# Consumer and ChangeNotifierProvider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

in this code iam trying to use viewmodel provider in my screen using consumer but it gives me that error.i tried too many changes but it didnt work

"

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:news_app/ui/categories/categories_details_view_model.dart';
    import 'package:news_app/ui/categories/category.dart';
    import 'package:news_app/ui/categories/category_tab_screen.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import '../../providers/my_provider.dart';
    import '../../shared/api_manager/api_manager.dart';
    import '../news/show_full_news_widget.dart';
    
    class CategoryDetails extends StatefulWidget {
      final Category category;
      const CategoryDetails(this.category, {super.key});
    
      @override
      State<CategoryDetails> createState() => _CategoryDetailsState();
    }
    
    class _CategoryDetailsState extends State<CategoryDetails> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        viewModel.getSources(widget.category.id);
      }
    
      var viewModel = CategoriesViewModel();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => viewModel,
            child: Consumer<CategoriesViewModel>(builder: (BuildContext context,
                CategoriesViewModel viewModel, Widget? child) {
              var provider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context);
              provider.indicator ??= true;
              if (viewModel.showLoading == true) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else if (viewModel.errorMessage != null) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Text(viewModel.errorMessage ??
                          "Connection is Lost please try again later"),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: const Text("Please try again"))
                  ],
                );
              }
    
              var sources = viewModel.newsSourcesList ?? [];
              return CategoryTabScreen(sources);
            }));
    
        //
      }
    }
```

the error "Every child of a RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox must have an ID in its parent data.
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot `consume` the provider right after you created it (since it's not available due to how `InheritedModel` widgets from within flutter work - long story short, the provider uses `InheritedModel` at it's core). You need to do it in a lower widget level. You can do this simply by wrapping the `Consumer` into a `Builder`.

Secondly, the value returned in `ChangeNotifierProvider`'s `create` callback should be `Provider` and call `notifyListeners` to trigger a rebuild in the consumers. Don't know what type is `CategoriesViewModel` so if you could share it I can help you better.

To offer you an example of best usage of the `Provider` patter in flutter:

The provider:

```dart
class CategoriesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<CategoryModel> categories = List.empty(growable: true);

  Future<void> fetchCategories() async {
    categories = await ...;
    notifyListeners();

    // TODO: add error handling as well
  }
}
```

Then your container of categories:

```dart
class CategoriesList extends StatelessWidget {
  ... constructor here
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => CategoriesProvider(),
      child: CategoriesList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your screen widget:

```dart
class CategoriesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ... constructor here
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CategoriesProvider>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, CategoriesProvider provider, Widget? child) {
        final categories = provider.categories;
        
        // Now you have the updated categories,
        // and every time the provider calls notifyListeners()
        // this builder is called again and your widget
        // is rebuilt.

        return ...; // Build your view here
      },
    );
  }
}
```